VisionOS Image Tracking
As I am trying to run the application with the vision Pro, I receive following error:
ar_image_tracking_provider_t <0x303d45340>: Failed to set up image tracking with error: No images were supplied.

i did add images in Assets under a “ref” folder. so normally it should work
this is my function
import Foundation
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import RealityKitContent


var arkitSession = ARKitSession()
@MainActor class ARKitViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    private let session = ARKitSession()
    private let imageTracking = ImageTrackingProvider(referenceImages: ReferenceImage.loadReferenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ref"))
    var entityMap : [UUID: ModelEntity] = [:]
    func runSession() async {
        Task {
            do {
                try await arkitSession.run([imageTracking])
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    var material = SimpleMaterial()

    var rootEntity = Entity()
    func updateImage(_ anchor: ImageAnchor) {
        if entityMap[anchor.id] == nil {
            let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
            entityMap[anchor.id] = entity
            rootEntity.addChild(entity)
            entity.transform = Transform(matrix: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func processUpdates() async {
        for await _ in imageTracking.anchorUpdates{
            print("test")
        }
    }
}

i don't know why it failed to set up and basically i am trying to use this code to detect an object ,static one?
exemple of these photos:

Did you put the images in Assets under a “ref” folder. You should also get rid of that floating Task

yes i did,also i did delete the floating Task

And also, I'm not sure if the code is correct, I followed the instruction giving in here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/tracking-images-in-3d-space

Creating AR Resource Group
You have to put images under a ref.arresourcegroup folder (which has an adhoc json file that created automatically), not under a regular ref folder. To do that, create you ref folder in Assets using contextual menu (do not specify .arresourcegroup extension, this folder will receive it automatically):

Place your 480x480 reference images in this folder and adjust their real-world size in the Inspector. You must use high-contrast, well-discernible, RGB-only (no Alpha-transparency) images. Also, avoid gradients and single-solid-colors in your reference images. Try to use colors that have an ideal contrast in black-and-white version of this image. Try not to use repetitive patterns like stripes or polka dots.

I'm sorry... Are you trying to track a real gadget, or you trying to track an image with a gadget?

iOS ARKit object tracking is not the same as visionOS ARKit image tracking. There's no object recognition in visionOS ARKit at the moment. Image recognition only...

If you need an object recognition functionality in visionOS, you have to train an MLModel and implement CoreML and Vision (2017) frameworks. This is absolutely different story.

i am trying to track real object

Image Tracking is only about recognizing an image. If the POV of the real gadget does not match the POV of the gadget in the picture (and this will be in 99.9999% of cases), ARKit will never generate its ImageAnchor. Since ARKit under visionOS does not yet have Object Tracking (we are all looking forward to WWDC'24'25), this means you will have to train MLModel for the Apple Vision framework. You'll also need AVFoundation to control a video stream.

Object Tracking in iOS, however, requires you to first scan the object from all angles. As a result of scanning, an .arobject file will be created which will contain a sparse point cloud. This is your reference object for iOS object detection. As you can see, there is nothing like this in visionOS yet (excluding visionOS Persona which is not available to developers).

Yep. At this moment – no way for object recognition in ARKit for visionOS. Your tech stack here will be AVFoundation, CoreML, Vision, CreateML and ARKit/RealityKit. But ARKit’s participation in this process will be reduced to a minimum (only to anchor generation).

Read about the six anchors that visionOS 1.2 now supports.

Create a new question, describe what you have already done, and describe the problem. Post one question at a time, do not try to solve all the problems in one question at once.

On StackOverflow, each area (AI, Video, UI, AR, etc) has its own professionals. I am sure that you will solve all your tasks step by step.

@kartbouni, Object Tracking has now been added to visionOS 2.0.
